# add space after every byte to a binary file

Tags: image, matlab, binary, byte, whitespace

I have a binary file of an image which is 256x256 array
I just want to add a space after every byte in this file
e.g *000101010101110101010100*
expected output: *00010101* *01011101* *01010100*
can any one suggest me to this using matlab prefarably

Comment: Have you already read the file? Do you have those 0/1 values in a matrix, vector, char array...?

Comment: is it for display purpose? or do you want to actually change the saved values?

Comment: Yes i have already have the file. I have a 256x256 array. what i did is took the transpose of of the matrix and resized it into 8192 rows and 8 columns. But this is resulting into many row addresses to read all the data. So i want to have every byte separated so i can read them directly from the same line.

Comment: Yes i want my fpga to read this data as byte. So unless i separate the bytes it will read entire line as single data value.

Comment: So you have a 65,536 byte binary file and you would like it to become 131,072 byte file where every second byte is a space. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... and to get the char array mentioned by [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24739064/2605073) you can do the following:

```
%edge length of image
edge = 256;

%open and read file
fid = fopen('imageData.txt');
C = fread(fid,[edge+2,edge]);
```

The `+2` actually depends on your file, does it contain carriage return? If not, leave it out.

```
% get char array
chararray = char(C(1:edge,:)');
```

Then I would proceed as follows:

```
wordlength = 8;
cellarray = mat2cell(chararray,ones(1,edge),wordlength*ones(1,edge/wordlength));
cellarray = cellfun(@(x) [x ' '],cellarray,'uni',0);
output = cell2mat(cellarray);
%// remove last column with unwanted space
output = output(:,end-1:end)
```

and write that to a file again.

---

regarding your comment, try this:

```
wordlength = 8;
cellarray = mat2cell(chararray,ones(1,edge),wordlength*ones(1,edge/wordlength));
fid2 = fopen( yourFilepath ,'w');
fprintf(fid2 , '%s\r\n', cellarray {:});
fclose(fid2);
```

Comment: when i try to make a character array as you said from my data file,there is a unwanted carriage return occurring at the end of line and every time an increasing number of bits are being put on a new line.(1st line has 256 bits in the character array,next line has 255 bits with one bit going on 3rd line,4th line has 254 bits with 2 bits on the 5th line ) This is then affecting entry of the space between bytes. How to avoid that

Comment: well the easiest way to help you would be if you provide your file. The point is: does your file have a line break? -> **+1**! Does your file have a carriage return? -> **+1**! Does it have both? **+2**  (in the line `C = fread(fid,[edge+2,edge]);`)

Comment: I got that working . Another thing, if i want to add a newline instead of space, how to do that ? i.e 00000000 00000000 instead of this i want every byte to go on  a new line.

Comment: Tried this code.What it is doing is just printing every byte column below each other.I would like to have every byte from a row go on a newline first followed by the next row.Ill re edit my requirement. Thanks for you help

Comment: I don't get it. Yes, I think you need much more specific in your question. Add an example file, please

Answer (score 1):

If you already have those 0/1 values in the form of a char array, such as

```
a =
101001011111011101010100
100101001010100000111111
100100100001011110110101
001010011111110000001010
```

you can do it this way:

```
n = 8; %// byte size
b = a(:,ceil(n/(n+1):n/(n+1):end)); %// repeat every n-th position
b(:,n+1:n+1:end) = ' '; %// replace those repeated positions by spaces
```

which gives

```
b =
10100101 11110111 01010100 
10010100 10101000 00111111 
10010010 00010111 10110101 
00101001 11111100 00001010
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple Perl one-liner:

```
perl -e '$/=\1;while(<>){print $_," ";}' < yourFile > newfile
```

The `$/=\1` sets the record separator so we read one byte at a time. Then we go into a loop reading one byte at a time, printing it out followed by a space till end of file.